# Python, reading a GPIO pin on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi, gpio, pins

Im trying to read a GPIO Pin on my Raspberry Pi with python and dont know how to read more Values than just `0(LOW)` or `1(HIGH)` (GPIO.input)  because i have this rotary Switch

```
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.IN)
VALUE=GPIO.input(14)
```

Comment: What values are you imagining that a GPIO pin can have, other than 0 or 1?  A rotary switch would presumably require multiple pins to interface - but you've given no details on which to base an answer.

Comment: Oh shoot, forgot the fact pins can only have 0 or 1....How would I have to set the switch up to be able to read more values ?

Comment: Think in binary, if you had two pins you could have values 0, 1, 2, 3 (i.e. 00 01 10 11)

Comment: So but there is no way to „digital read“ to read data out of sensors like you can on an arduino for example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.
gpiozero:

```
import Button
from time import sleep

button = Button(2)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        print("Pressed")
    else:
        print("Released")
    sleep(1)
```